# Cubemap skybox in Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox, shader-graph

How to make a cubemap shader for a skybox in a shader graph? My shader is on the screenshot, but it does not work. I couldn't find a solution on the internet.

[Shader Graph Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp4cG.png)

Comment: You ever figure this out?>

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Sample Reflected Cubemap` instead of `Sample Cubemap` may help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.